# SQL Server 2008: complex Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, database-cursor

I have a table called `Employees`:

```
BeginYear  |   EndYear   |    Name
1974           1983           Robert
```

For each record in `Employees` I need to insert each year into a new table called `EmployeeYears`

So:

```
For Each Record in Employees
    For i as int = Begin Year to End year
        INSERT i, Name into EmployeeYears
```

Any Way to do this in SQL...possibly with cursors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of it is using a WITH statement to create all the records and use them to insert into your final table.

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT Year = BeginYear
         , Name
  FROM   Employees
  UNION ALL
  SELECT q.Year + 1
         , q.Name
  FROM   q
         INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.Name = q.Name
                                   AND e.EndYear > q.Year
)
INSERT INTO EmployeeYears
SELECT * FROM q
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Testdata**

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (BeginYear INTEGER, EndYear INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(32))
CREATE TABLE EmployeeYears (Year INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO Employees
  SELECT 1974, 1976, 'Robert'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1972, 1975, 'Lieven'
```

**Results**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    EmployeeYears
ORDER BY Name, Year

1972    Lieven
1973    Lieven
1974    Lieven
1975    Lieven
1974    Robert
1975    Robert
1976    Robert
```

Comment: Would this however only get the next year? what if there are multiple years?

Comment: @William, I have just checked it using SSMS and afaik it does what you need.

Comment: This works due to recursion, but you'll likely very quickly hit a recursion limit.

Comment: @Timothy, the recursion limit can be lifted (not to infinity) but OP should give it a try.

Comment: Could you include the code to remove the limit. Also, I tried testing the code and it seems to only give back 1 result due to the INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Timothy, limit removed. I have tested this with two records. My testdata has been added to the answer.

Comment: Very nice... I think this is the best solution here, specifically because the recursion is based on 'years' which is likely not going to have data that would cause an overflow.

Comment: This made my mgt studio crash

Comment: @William, how many records does your employee table hold? How many years appart on average for each record?

Comment: Well, if we then take your example to be an average, that would insert 12 mil * (1983 - 1974) = 108 mil records. I can assume SQL Server choking on that amount. An alternative could be to split this up in batches of +-1 million records each.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a  numbers table you can join on it to get the individual year records and avoid using a cursor. I just poulated the numbers table with number from 1965 to 968, but a realife numbers table (which also would not be a temp table as shown below for example purposes, but one that lives in your schema) would probably have several million records as it is useful for a lot of comparing.

```
create table #Numbers (Number int)
insert into #Numbers
select 1965
union
select 1966
union 
select 1967
union 
select 1968

create table #employees (name varchar (50), beginyear int, endyear int)
insert into #employees
select 'Dick', 1966, 1968
union all 
select 'harry', 1965, 1967
union all 
select 'tom', 1955, 1966

insert into EmployeeYears (Name, [Year])
select Name, n.number 
from #Employees e
join #Numbers n on  n.number between e.beginyear and e.endyear
order by name
```

Comment: Can you please explain further, i do not believe I have a numbers table.

Comment: True, but that's like saying... "if you had the result, you'd have the result."... what he's asking for *IS* a 'numbers table'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you actually have to do a loop... I'd prefer not using CURSORS, but this case sorta makes sense... anyway, here's the code as just a straight loop to show you that you can do that kind of code in SQL:

```
DECLARE @Employee VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @BeginYear INT, @EndYear INT, @i INT

SET @Employee = ''

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    SET @Employee = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM Employees ORDER BY Name WHERE Name > @Employee)

    IF @Employee IS NULL BREAK

    SELECT @BeginYear = BeginYear, @EndYear = EndYear FROM Employees WHERE Name = @Employee

    SET @i = @BeginYear

    WHILE (@i <= @EndYear)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EmployeeYears (Year, Name) VALUES (@i, @Employee)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, but doing a select top one w/ that where and order clause on this table would end up taking a very long time

Comment: Shouldn't you increment the `YEAR` somewhere in there?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that... regarding the "take a long time", you could first put it in a temp table already sorted. Basically, you have a design problem and now you're trying to fix it, the solution's aren't going to be pretty.

Comment: WHILE (1=1)
  Won't this create and infinite loop?

Comment: @William, no, the while loop is ok because it has the break code: `IF @Employee IS NULL BREAK`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT BeginYear, EndYear, Name
    FROM Employees
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BeginYear+1, EndYear, Name
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE BeginYear < EndYear
)  
INSERT INTO EmployeeYears (Year, Name)
SELECT BeginYear, Name
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Name, BeginYear
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "BeginYear" of recursive query "CTE".

Comment: @William - Sorry, the #Temp1 got copied from my test, updated my answer, thanks. I tried the code above and it worked fine, assuming BeginYear is an `INT`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive procedure. Llike the one bellow:

```
CREATE Procedure InsertYear
    @Name ....
    @BeginYear ...
    @EndYear ...
AS
{
     INSERT INTO  EmployeeYears  VALUES(@BeginYear, @Name);
     SET  @BeginYear = @BeginYear + 1
     IF @BeginYear < @EndYear
     BEGIN
         InsertYear(@Name, @BeginYear, @EndYear)
     END

     RETURN
}
```

Comment: This would work well as a ud function, however, i would still need to implement it for each record in employees table

Answer (score 0):

You could do this but it will fail if Begin or end exceeds 2047

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeYears (number, name)
SELECT v.number, e.name
FROM 
    Employees e
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values v on 
    v.number between beginYear and endYear
```